# Why won't my X Server won't start as a regular user?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, boot, x11

X won't start on my main machine. I can start it as root, but then it only logs me in as root -- I can't use my regular user account. When I start up, it flashes a black screen, then hangs at "Stopping userspace bootsplash".

What can I do to fix this? I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 x64.

**Edit**: My `Xorg.0.log` is [here](http://pastebin.com/WhuUXAdh)

Comment: Can you get into safe/recovery mode during start-up? That offers some options to fix X.

Comment: Yes. I tried that. But I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem.
Turns out, my language setting for my user was messed up, so I fixed it in root, and it started working perfectly fine again.

Answer (score 1):

If it does work for root, then I would look if your /home/ is not full. Try:

```
df -h
```

If it's full, make some space.
As a workaround you can create a new user from console:

```
root@box# useradd -m another
```

setup a password:

```
root@box# passwd another
```

and retry.

Another workaround worth to try is to reset your gnome settings in case you messed them up somehow:

```
cd ~you
mv .compiz .compiz_old
mv .config .config_old
mv .gconf .gconf_old
mv .gnome2 .gnome2_old
mv .local .local_old
```

and try to relogin.

Comment: Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             119G   96G   17G  86% /
none                  1.9G  704K  1.9G   1% /dev
none                  1.9G  168K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.9G  388K  1.9G   1% /var/run
none                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /var/lock

Comment: And that didn't work...

Comment: I [fixed it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/x-server-wont-start/18297#18297). Thanks for your effort, though.