# Arch: can't get X to work under regular user

Tags: arch-linux, xorg

I can `startx` as root, but can't as a regular user. I compared logs and there's the difference:

root:

```
#> cat Xorg.0.log | egrep '(EE|WW)'
[  1507.647] Current Operating System: Linux hostname 3.17.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 30 20:49:39 CET 2014 x86_64
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1507.658] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1507.668] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[  1507.672] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
[  1507.674] (WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
[  1507.864] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "VendorName" is not used
[  1507.864] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "ModelName" is not used
[  1508.002] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
```

(and X starts )

regular user:

```
$> cat Xorg.0.log | egrep '(EE|WW)'
[   533.461] Current Operating System: Linux hostname 3.17.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 30 20:49:39 CET 2014 x86_64
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   533.465] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[   533.482] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[   533.486] (WW) LoadKernelModule: Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed
[   533.487] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
[   533.488] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
[   533.488] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   533.489] (WW) LoadKernelModule: Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed
[   533.490] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
[   533.490] (EE) fglrx(0): The graphics processor is already set to console mode, set X mode fail. Cannot start X.
[   533.490] (EE) fglrx(0): PreInit failed
[   533.490] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[   533.490] (EE) 
[   533.490] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   533.490] (EE) 
[   533.490] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/me/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   533.490] (EE) 
[   533.492] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The first difference is

```
LoadKernelModule: Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed
```

**What can I do to get it working?**

Similar question: [Why won't my X Server won't start as a regular user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/why-wont-my-x-server-wont-start-as-a-regular-user)

Can't it be the same problem? his x log looks different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should double check the permissions on `/usr/bin/X`, it should have SUID/GUID bits set:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 10184 Jan  3  2013 /usr/bin/X*
```

change with `sudo chmod ug+s /usr/bin/X`